# Get sorted values of Matrix in Java

Tags: java, sorting, matrix

I'm totally new in Java. 
I need to "sort" the value of a matrix in Java but I don't know how to do.

This is my matrix:

```
double matrix = new double[3][3];
// fill matrix with some random values
```

The result of the matrix could be something like this:

```
3,4    9.4    7.7
4,1    3.48   9.9
1,6    3.5    5.3
```

Now I need to get the i & j value of this matrix in decrease order of the corresponding value. There are some way to do that?

In this case the vector with the sorted value it should contain something like this: 
(1,2), (0,1), (0,2), (2,2) ... (2,1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Java 8** you can do this with Lambda:

```
int rows = matrix.lenght;
int cols = matix[0].lenght;

List<List<Integer>>orderedSavingsList = IntStream.range(0, rows).mapToObj(i ->
            IntStream.range(0, cols).mapToObj(j ->
                    new double[]{i, j, matrix[i][j]}
            )
    )
    .flatMap(x -> x).filter(t -> t[0] < t[1])
    .sorted((a, b) -> Double.compare(b[2], a[2]))
    .map(a -> Arrays.asList((int) a[0], (int) a[1]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

After that try to print the list with:

```
orderedSavingsList.forEach(System.out::println);
```